# rsync won't delete file that was deleted on source

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot, source

I'm using [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) to back up some servers of mine. It works fine, except it won't delete files that have been deleted on the source server. Here is where I give rsnapshot the options to pass along to rsync:

```
rsync_long_args --stats    --delete        --numeric-ids   --delete-excluded
```

It seems to have something to do with the `--stats` option, because whenever I have this instead:

```
rsync_long_args --delete        --numeric-ids   --delete-excluded
```

It will remove the files that were deleted on the source. Does anyone know why this is? I'd really like to be able to keep the `--stats output`, and whenever I put it anywhere else I don't seem to get the output.

Comment: I've tested these options locally, for me it seems that everything works fine. But how do you use `rsnapshot` for backups?

Normally `rsnapshot` is meant to be used for archiving data, not for backups. If you want to backup your data it is probably better to use `rsync` directly.